# Unable to locate package libsslcommon2-dev in Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: apt, 18.04, package-management, repository

I'm trying to install `libsslcommon2-dev` in ubuntu 18.04, but it throws me the following error:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package libsslcommon2-dev
```

Earlier I was able to install it in Ubuntu 16.04.

Comment: The package was removed from Debian, so it got removed from Ubuntu: https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=870952 What do you need it for?

Comment: @Olorin I need to install php mongodb driver which require libsslcommon2-dev

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As user [Olorin](https://askubuntu.com/users/760903/olorin) mentions the `libsslcommon2-dev` package was [removed from Debian in 2017](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=8709520). You probably want to use the `libssl-dev` package instead:

```
sudo apt install libssl-dev
```

That's assuming you want to use the OpenSSL library in C, which will provide the header files.